# How to define function inside macro in cmake

Tags: cmake

I've been working in a software project which used cmake, where the file structure looked something like this:

- cmake
- tests
- build
- src

  - module1
  - module2
  - module3

    - submod1
    - submod2

      - impl

        - backend1
        - backend2

Each one of the folders contains one CMakeLists.txt, which basically adds more files to the source code files list that is defined in the CMakeLists.txt present in the src folder. The thing is, it wasn't practical to pass all these variables up all along the scope stack with PARENT_SCOPE, so we were using properties for that.

It was working well until we decided that to ease testing, it would be useful to have each one of the submodules built on an static library. And so I've been working in a macro that looks like this:

```
macro(define_build_unit unit_name unit_root)
  function(${unit_name}_add_sources)
    message(STATUS ${ARGN})
    file(RELATIVE_PATH _relPath ${unit_root} "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
    foreach(_src ${ARGN})
      if(_relPath)
        list(APPEND ${unit_name}_SRCS "${_relPath}/${_src}")
      else()
        list(APPEND ${unit_name}_SRCS "${_src}")
      endif()
    endforeach()
    if(_relPath)
      set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY ${unit_name}_SRCS ${${unit_name}_SRCS})
    endif()
  endfunction()

  function(${unit_name}_add_link_deps)
    foreach(_dep ${ARGN})
      list(APPEND ${unit_name}_DEPS "${_dep}")
    endforeach()
    set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY ${unit_name}_DEPS ${${unit_name}_DEPS})
  endfunction()

  function(${unit_name}_add_include_dirs)
    foreach(_inc ${ARGN})
      list(APPEND ${unit_name}_INC_DIRS "${_inc}")
    endforeach()
    set_property(GLOBAL APPEND PROPERTY ${unit_name}_INC_DIRS ${${unit_name}_INC_DIRS})
  endfunction()
endmacro()
```

The problem is that ARGN is being substituted from the define_build_unit macro, and not from the corresponding function. I've tried all the combinations of macro/function and nothing seems to work.

So, the question is: is there a better way for variable arguments in cmake than the ARGN global variable? Something like macro(my_macro args...)? If not, does somebody know of an equivalent way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question has already been accepted however, in my case I really did need to have the function definition inside of a macro. The reason? I wanted to programmatically generate specialized functions based on the macro parameters. This meant taking advantage of the text replacement functionality of macros, while producing a dynamically created function that could then be used in the rest of the build.

```
macro(build_my_func func_name)
    message(${ARGV})
    function(my_${func_name})
        set(func_ARGV ARGV)
        message(${${func_ARGV}})
    endfunction()
endmacro()
```

The "trick" is to set a variable inside the function that contains the NAME of the variable you want to access, in this case `ARGV`. Then, it can be accessed as a variable-variable, ie: `${${func_ARGV}}`. In this instance, the inner variable `${func_ARGV}` is replaced with ARGV, ultimately resolving to `${ARGV}`.

It's a little bit of a workaround but can be a useful way to access any variables that the outer macro may stamp out. It can also be used to cache macro parameters as values to be used in the function to customize its behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Change the outer macro into a `function` as well.

From the CMake [`macro` documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/macro.html):

> Note that the parameters to a macro and values such as ARGN are not
>   variables in the usual CMake sense. They are string replacements much
>   like the C preprocessor would do with a macro.

That means, *all* of your references to `${ARGN}` inside the macro will get replaced with the macro's parameters when instantiating the macro. This is in particular also true for any occurrences inside the nested function.

Macros are kind of a weird beast, since their syntax suggests they work like ordinary functions but their mechanism for handling parameters is completely different from the usual CMake variables. If you can, you should stick with `functions` whenever possible to avoid those pitfalls.

```
function(build_my_function func_name)
    message(${ARGV})
    function(my_${func_name})
        message(${ARGV})
    endfunction()
endfunction()

build_my_function(foo bar)  # prints "foobar", the arguments to the outer function
my_foo(baz)                 # prints "baz", the arguments to the inner function
```